# Como simplificar esta comparação?

Tags: c#

Muitas vezes caio na seguinte situação :

Por exemplo em c#:

```
string variavel= "x";

boolean b = (variavel == "a" || variavel == "d" ||.....|| variavel== "y");
```

> Existe alguma maneira de simplificar pra algo como b =("a" || "b" ||
>   .... ||"y")?

Além de ser chato acho que vai melhorar muito a legibilidade caso exista algo parecido. Switch case não ajuda muito .

Comment: Sim use `in_array()` ;)

Comment: Você precisa escolher uma linguaguem, a forma de resolver o problema muda de uma para outra.

Comment: Obrigado rray , o intuito saber como vcs resolvem essa situação no dia a dia . A solução do array é ótima ! Eu não entendo porque as linguagens no geral não vem com algo intuitivo como um operador |= "a'',"b","c"

Comment: Em C#, com recurso a LINQ, pode fazer o seguinte: `bool b = new string[] {"a", "b", ...}.Any(s => s == variavel);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em C# pode fazer o seguinte, com recurso a `LINQ`:

```
bool b = new string[] {"a", "b", ...}.Any(s => s == variavel);
```

Veja [aqui um exemplo do codigo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L8a03J).

Comment: Excelente !! Muito obrigado Omni !

Comment: por estar criando um vetor isso não compromete o desempenho?

Comment: @Pilati depende de como ocorre a comparação. Em termos ilustrativos, o vector e perfeitamente aceitável. Numa aplicacao onde a comparação seja feita sempre contra o mesmo vector, a solução seria criar o vector uma vez e usa-lo nas comparações subsequentes. Mas como disse depende do caso especifico do OP (que não e dado a entender na pergunta).

Answer (score 2):

Em C, se as "strings" forem apenas caracteres, eu usaria `strchr()`

```
char *b;
char variavel[100] = "x";
b = strchr("ad...y", *variavel);
// usa b como boolean
if (b) ok();
```

Se as strings forem efectivamente sequencias de 0 ou mais caracteres, optaria por uma sequencia de `if`s encadeados

```
char variavel[100] = "XPTO";
if (strcmp(variavel, "AAAA") == 0) ok();
else if (strcmp(variavel, "DDDD") == 0) ok();
else if (strcmp(variavel, "....") == 0) ok();
else if (strcmp(variavel, "YYYY") == 0) ok();
```

Answer (score 1):

Não consigo pensar numa alternativa à comparações sucessivas.
O melhor a fazer seria colocar cada comparação em uma linha diferente como no caso abaixo, mas só melhoraria na visibilidade:

```
bool b = (
    variavel == "a" ||
    variavel == "b" ||
    ...             ||
    variavel == "y"
)
```